# Reading AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID of Recurring Event is Causing Issues

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm finding that when I read the GlobalAppointmentID of a recurring event in Outlook via my Excel-VBA code, things start acting odd.

Here's part of the code that I've been using to try to understand the root cause of this behavior:

```
For Each otItem In resCal
    If otItem.Class = olAppointment Then
        Set cItm = otItem

        If calItem.Subject = "Coffee Date" Then
            Debug.Print "Coffee orig " & cItm.Start
            Debug.Print "Coffee orig 1.1 " & cItm.Start
            Debug.Print cItm.GlobalAppointmentID
            Debug.Print cItm.GlobalAppointmentID
            Debug.Print "Coffee orig 1.5 " & cItm.Start
        End If

    End If
Next otItem
```

This produces the following output:

- Coffee orig 4/16/2015 10:00:00 AM
- Coffee orig 1.1 4/16/2015 10:00:00 AM
- [Global Appointment ID redacted, but identical]
- [Global Appointment ID redacted, but identical]
- Coffee orig 1.5 2/19/2015 10:00:00 AM

4/16 is the instance of the recurring event that I would like to record. However, when I call the GlobalAppointmentID property, it changes the value of the .Start property to that of the first instance of the recurring event. I've tested and can implement a workaround that involves me storing the start date in a variable before calling GlobalAppointmentID, however I would like to try to diagnose and fix the root cause of the issue to ensure that it isn't causing any problems that I haven't noticed yet. Can anyone shed some light on what is causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue without a loop? Just with a single appointment item? Is it an Exchange profile?

Comment: I didn't think to test this. I just did, and actually the problem does not occur when I call the AppointmentItem by index instead of looping via For Each. And this email address is for work, and I'm pretty sure we use Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently took another look at my code and determined the source of the problem. Here’s the snippets of code that were causing the problem:

```
With oItms
    .Sort "[Start]", False
    .IncludeRecurrences = True
End With

Set rCal = oItms.Restrict("[Start] >= '" & CStr(date) & "'")

With rCal
    .Sort "[Start]", False
    .IncludeRecurrences = True
End With
```

Specifically, running the “.Sort” and the “.IncludeRecurrances” on rCal without calling the “.Restrict” method caused the problem. I determined that the 2nd “With” was redundant as is, so I removed it. I can now call any property in any order, without having to worry about the values changing.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem does not occur when I call the AppointmentItem by index instead of looping via For Each

I'd recommend using the for loop instead and releasing the object as soon as possible. This is particularly important if your code attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. Declare an object in the function scope (loop scope) and set it to Nothing to release the reference to the object as soon as possible.